# How2 - Slidervalues via JS to PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, json

I would like to use the input of 3 sliders to calculate a resulting value via a given formular. My or better our problem is, that this calculation shall be part of a riddle for a Webdesingers wedding present. So we need a way to ensure that the expert can't find an easy solution in the source code, while the rest of us has no clue of web programming at all. So everything is learning by doing right now. From my general understanding the best way to conceal the formular is to calculate everything on the server side, while the result will be displayed on the clients browser. So PHP is the way to do the calculation on the server.

So for the start I've created the website with the following slider inputs

```
<div class="slidecontainer r1">
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="r1">
<span id="r1_output">Test</span> Vegas Baby
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer r2">
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="r2">
<span id="r2_output">Test</span> Och Nico
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer c1">
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="c1">
<span id="c1_output">Test</span>&nbsp;&#181;F
</div>

<div class="f1">
<output id="freq">10</output>
</div>
```

Than some JS to transfer the slider values to PHP

```
var r1_slider = document.getElementById("r1");
var r2_slider = document.getElementById("r2");
var c1_slider = document.getElementById("c1");
var r1_output = document.getElementById("r1_output");
var r2_output = document.getElementById("r2_output");
var c1_output = document.getElementById("c1_output");
var freq_out = document.getElementById("freq");
r1_output.innerHTML = r1_slider.value; // Display the default slider value
r2_output.innerHTML = r2_slider.value; // Display the default slider value
c1_output.innerHTML = c1_slider.value; // Display the default slider value

grundlagen = function() {
const url = './3k5-dateien/3k5.php';
// The data we are going to send in our request
let data = {
    r1: r1_slider.value,
    r2: r2_slider.value,
    c1: c1_slider.value
}
// The parameters we are gonna pass to the fetch function
let fetchData = { 
    method: 'POST', 
    body: data,
    headers: new Headers()
}
fetch(url, fetchData)
    .then(function(data) {
    });
}


// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
r1_slider.oninput = function() {
    r1_output.innerHTML = this.value;
    grundlagen();        
}

r2_slider.oninput = function() {
    r2_output.innerHTML = this.value;
    grundlagen();
}

c1_slider.oninput = function() {
    c1_output.innerHTML = this.value;
    grundlagen();
}
```

but the problem seems to be, that the PHP script won't be exectued at all.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");

echo "drin";

#$doc = new DomDocument();
#$doc->loadHTMLFile('../3k4prozent.htm');
#$thediv = $doc->getElementById('result');
#echo $thediv->textContent;


# Get JSON as a string
#$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');

# Get as an object
#$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
#if((($json_obj.r1+2*$json_obj.r2)*$json_obj.c1)>30 and (($json_obj.r1+2*$json_obj.r2)*$json_obj.c1)36)
#{

#}
?>
```

Can anybody give me an hint on how to procede from here on? How can I check that the values are transfered correctly to the PHP function at all?

BR Chris

Comment: add an aditional '.catch(error => console.error(error))' to see if it goes there, also it might be because the 'url' isn't found, could you show your project file structure?